# MvvmCross - Getting TargetInvocationException and SIGABRT while disposing a binding in UISlider

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, uislider

I'm working on a project with Xamarin.iOS and MvvmCross (v5.6.3) and I have a very typical UISlider on one view controller with its value binded to a `float` property on its view-model.

```
set.Bind(MySlider).For(x => x.Value).To(vm => vm.FloatProperty).TwoWay();
```

When the view unloads and try to dispose the existing bindings (like while navigating to another view-model) I'm getting the following unhandled exception with a `SIGABRT`:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException: UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.
  at UIKit.UIApplication.EnsureUIThread () [0x00023] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:88 
  at UIKit.UIControl.RemoveTarget (Foundation.NSObject target, System.IntPtr sel, UIKit.UIControlEvent events) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIControl.g.cs:235 
  at UIKit.UIControl.RemoveTarget (System.EventHandler notification, UIKit.UIControlEvent events) [0x00057] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIControl.cs:116 
  at UIKit.UIControl.remove_ValueChanged (System.EventHandler value) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIControl.cs:209 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00046] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:313 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs:229 
  at MvvmCross.Platform.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription`1[TSource].RemoveEventHandler () [0x00024] in <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Platform.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription`1[TSource].Dispose (System.Boolean disposing) [0x00003] in <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Platform.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription`1[TSource].Dispose () [0x00000] in <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.iOS.Target.MvxUISliderValueTargetBinding.Dispose (System.Boolean isDisposing) [0x0001b] in <614c9ef828c14ba687a40ec2656f480f>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxBinding.Finalize () [0x00000] in <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0 
2018-04-09 23:15:20.210 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] Unhandled managed exception:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00046] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:313 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs:229 
  at MvvmCross.Platform.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription`1[TSource].RemoveEventHandler () [0x00024] in <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Platform.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription`1[TSource].Dispose (System.Boolean disposing) [0x00003] in <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Platform.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription`1[TSource].Dispose () [0x00000] in <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.iOS.Target.MvxUISliderValueTargetBinding.Dispose (System.Boolean isDisposing) [0x0001b] in <614c9ef828c14ba687a40ec2656f480f>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxBinding.Finalize () [0x00000] in <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0 
 --- inner exception ---
UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread. (UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.EnsureUIThread () [0x00023] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:88 
  at UIKit.UIControl.RemoveTarget (Foundation.NSObject target, System.IntPtr sel, UIKit.UIControlEvent events) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIControl.g.cs:235 
  at UIKit.UIControl.RemoveTarget (System.EventHandler notification, UIKit.UIControlEvent events) [0x00057] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIControl.cs:116 
  at UIKit.UIControl.remove_ValueChanged (System.EventHandler value) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIControl.cs:209 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
2018-04-09 23:15:20.210 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical: Stacktrace:

2018-04-09 23:15:20.211 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical: 
Native stacktrace:

2018-04-09 23:15:20.212 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical:  0   MyProject.iOS                       0x00000001038b4574 mono_handle_native_crash + 244
2018-04-09 23:15:20.212 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical:  1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x000000010bbecf5a _sigtramp + 26
2018-04-09 23:15:20.213 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical:  2   ???                                 0x0000000103dd308a 0x0 + 4359794826
2018-04-09 23:15:20.213 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical:  3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x000000010b8820eb abort + 127
2018-04-09 23:15:20.213 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical:  4   MyProject.iOS                       0x0000000103a5b2df xamarin_unhandled_exception_handler + 47
2018-04-09 23:15:20.214 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical:  5   MyProject.iOS                       0x000000010391b854 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 148
2018-04-09 23:15:20.214 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical:  6   MyProject.iOS                       0x00000001039c2a3e mono_thread_internal_unhandled_exception + 110
2018-04-09 23:15:20.215 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical:  7   MyProject.iOS                       0x000000010391d15a mono_gc_run_finalize + 842
2018-04-09 23:15:20.215 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical:  8   MyProject.iOS                       0x00000001039fc9ba sgen_gc_invoke_finalizers + 234
2018-04-09 23:15:20.215 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical:  9   MyProject.iOS                       0x000000010391eae4 finalizer_thread + 756
2018-04-09 23:15:20.215 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical:  10  MyProject.iOS                       0x00000001039c3600 start_wrapper + 704
2018-04-09 23:15:20.215 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical:  11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010bbfe6c1 _pthread_body + 340
2018-04-09 23:15:20.216 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical:  12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010bbfe56d _pthread_body + 0
2018-04-09 23:15:20.216 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical:  13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010bbfdc5d thread_start + 13
2018-04-09 23:15:20.216 MyProject.iOS[73770:3302608] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

The binding works fine, this happens only when <del>I try to navigate to another view-model</del> **the view is being unloaded**.

Am I missing something? Or is this maybe a bug on MvvmCross?

**Edit:**
Finally checked that this issue occurs when the view is being unloaded, regardless I'm navigating to another view-model or not. I've removed the references where I'm pointing to a navigation issue.

Comment: And how are you doing the navigation?

Comment: Hi, @apineda! I've edited the question with more detail about this issue. Although navigating to another view-model is the main reason why the view is being unloaded, this is not an issue only while navigating, but when unloading the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently a bug in MvvmCross 5.x.x with respect to the `UISlider`. The issue has been fixed with [PR 2750](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/2750) which will ship in version 6.0.0

In the meantime, you should be able to override the binding to fix it for your project by creating a custom binding with the fix. The issue is in the [`Dispose`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/master/MvvmCross/Binding/iOS/Target/MvxUISliderValueTargetBinding.cs#L59).

```
public class FixedMvxUISliderValueTargetBinding : MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding<UISlider>
{
    private IDisposable _subscription;

    public FixedMvxUISliderValueTargetBinding(object target, PropertyInfo targetPropertyInfo) 
        : base(target, targetPropertyInfo) { }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        var view = target as UISlider;
        if (view == null) return;
        view.Value = (float)value;
    }

    private void HandleSliderValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var view = View;
        if (view == null) return;
        FireValueChanged(view.Value);
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode => MvxBindingMode.TwoWay;

    public override void SubscribeToEvents()
    {
        var slider = View;
        if (slider == null)
        {
            MvxBindingTrace.Trace(
                MvxTraceLevel.Error, 
                "Error - UISlider is null in MvxUISliderValueTargetBinding");
            return;
        }
        _subscription = slider.WeakSubscribe(
            nameof(slider.ValueChanged), 
            HandleSliderValueChanged);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            _subscription?.Dispose();
            _subscription = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `Setup.cs` register the binding. Note, make sure that you call `base.FillTargetFactories` first.

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
    base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
    registry.RegisterPropertyInfoBindingFactory(
        typeof(FixedMvxUISliderValueTargetBinding),
        typeof(UISlider),
        nameof(UISlider.Value));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was already on track for this, but wasn't able to find a fix. Unfortunately the custom target binding is not being called, I'm getting the same exception and it's still calling for `MvvmCross.Binding.iOS.Target.MvxUISliderValueTargetBinding.Dispose (System.Boolean isDisposing)`. Noticed that in your `FillTargetFactories` you placed the `Type targetType` as `typeof(UIStepper)` and not `typeof(UISlider)`. I assumed this was a typo and changed for the later. Besides that, everything else was copied&pasted.

Comment: @JordiVilaplana, yeah, thanks that was indeed a typo, it should be `UISlider`. In terms of it not being called, you could try changing the third parameter to something more custom like "SilderValue", and then binding in your view to it.

Comment: Changed the 3rd parameter to `"FixedValue"` (to make clear this was fixed :) ) and the binding to `set.Bind(MySlider).For("FixedValue").To(vm => vm.FloatProperty).TwoWay();` as well. Now it works like a charm. :) Accepting your answer.

Comment: Awesome, I though setting it to "Value" would override the existing binding "Value". But glad it sovled your issue :)

Comment: I've placed the `"FixedValue"` as a `public const string BindingName` in `FixedMvxUISliderValueTargetBinding` so I don't have to c&p a hardcoded string everywhere. Don't like hardcoded values. :) Didn't try to register the binding as `"Value"`, too afraid to break anything up. :P

Answer (score 1):

> you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.

Try to invoke your navigate method in UIThread.

```
this.InvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
    //navigate 
});
```

If above doesn't work, you can try to close UI Thread check.

```
var previous = UIApplication.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls;  
UIApplication.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;  
//navigate 
UIApplication.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = previous;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Cole! Unfortunately your solution isn't working. I've edited the question with more detail about this issue, please feel free to check the edits.